# MYSQL MyISAM - Stalled ALTER ADD INDEX FULLTEXT?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, myisam

question is : should I (always) see the temporary index file growing steadily even if slowly?

---

I am adding a FULLTEXT index on 2 columns to a fairly large MyISAM table (75M rows; 16GB)

I was expecting a lengthy process and do indeed get the dreaded "Repair with keycache".

The process has been going for 30h+. The temporary data (#sql-stuff.MYD) file has not been modified in the past 24h, which is probably OK. I am puzzled however, because the index (#sql-stuff.MYI) has been static for the past 12hrs, and is barely larger than the table's original index (16.47G vs 16.18).

Can someone describe to me the FT indexing process? In particular, should I (always) see the temporary index file growing steadily even if slowly?

(btw, the process had been successful in a previous iteration, at 60M+ records.)

Comment: Is there something keeping you from using a solution like sphinx?

Comment: ignorance? :) (I might look into it. This specific issue is not recurrent and the whole project works reasonably well)

Comment: Take a look at it, it might be a fit. It's an FT search engine that integrates very closely with mysql. MyISAM + lots of data is a World of Pain. Doubly so if you're only suffering MyISAM because you want the FT.

Comment: Looks like Sphinx is not easy to cajole into working with MAMP/OSX. I'll wait to see how things go. ATM I am not worried/concerned, just puzzled -- I was really expecting to be able to trace the progress by looking at the temp tables. (but thanks for mentioning Sphinx)

Comment: Try `lsof`, and maybe `iotop` for hints to what's going on.  In some cases, MySQL server creates temp tables and immediately deletes them, while holding the filehandle open.  The way *nix handles file unlinking, this causes the space allocated for the temp file to be automagically freed if the process crashes or is killed.  They'll show up as open and deleted in `lsof`.